# Class 'Model_register' not found

Tags: kohana

Good day ladies and gentlemen, i've upgraded my kohana from 3.1.x to a latest 3.3.x version and now im getting an error:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_register' not found

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Well, do you have a `Model_register` class?

Comment: No, i have not, weird, how could this be? kohana 3.1.x incompatible with 3.3.x ?

Comment: Anyway, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the upgrade guides for  **[3.1.x => 3.2.x](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/upgrading)** and **[3.2.x => 3.3.x](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading)**.

With 3.2.x Kohana changed the naming conventions to be PSR-0 compliant. That means if a class called `Kohana_Core` is currently located in `classes/kohana/core.php` you have to change it to `classes/Kohana/Core.php`. You will have to either upgrade all your modules to the current versions, or fix the naming yourself (which could be a lot of work).

The issue you are seeing is most likely related to the change of the naming conventions. If it isn't, what is the module that caues this error?

Comment: PSR-0 - is not a problem, this class really doesnt exist, module is my custom(authorization), but it was working ok before.

Comment: Maybe i can replace $reg = new Model_Register(); with another "new style" code?